# Why would prime (aka ') raise an error in the following: pred add (b, b': Book, n: Name, a: Addr) { b’.addr = b.addr + n -> a }?

Tags: alloy

- I have Alloy 6.1.0 running on Windows 10
- I have "Software Abstractions" text by Daniel Jackson and working through book.
- I am at the examples in the "Whirlwind Tour" and section 2.2 "Dynamics:
  Adding Operations".
- Verbatim from the book I have coded up the following:

```
    module tour/addressBook1
    
    sig Name, Addr {}
    sig Book {
      addr: Name -> lone Addr
    }
    
    pred show (b: Book) {
    #b.addr >1
    #Name.(b.addr) > 1
    }
    
    pred add (b,b': Book, n: Name, a: Addr) {
    b'.addr = b.addr + n -> a
    }
    
    run add for 3 but 2 Book
```

Results in:

```
Syntax error at line 13 column 14:
There are 3 possible tokens that can appear here:
, : =
```

Against the prime (') in

```
pred add (b,b': Book, ...
```

I understand the version of Alloy in the book will be behind the one I am using, but surely prime is still a thing, so it isn't ituitive why I am getting this syntax error.

Is there a module I need load nowadays?

I have also jumped ahead to Figure 2.7 and just snipped the full model out, rather than use my hand coded attempts.  Same error at the same point.

Comment: Looking at the examples that come with Alloy 6.1.0 I have to note they use " in place of ' and "" in place of ", so I will need dig a little deeper into the reason for that change in approach.

Comment: Bottom of the page https://alloytools.org/alloy6.html talks about compatability and so-called "new symbols", including the symbol ' - discusses but not really explains use of " in place of '.  That is not an intuitive statement if the symbol ' was being used previously as evidenced by the examples in the book.  Of course, alloy 6 examples of use of symbol ' at https://haslab.github.io/formal-software-design/overview/index.html must be the "new" use of the symbol ' (I suppose)?

Answer (score 1):

Good question, Asterion! As you suspected, the prime symbol is now special in Alloy 6, with the addition of the new temporal features from Electrum. So you'll need to use a different symbol to run the examples from the book. Sorry about this. It's the one cost of the lovely new temporal features.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, the new features are great!  Keep up the good work.